# Animate UIView frame change without move animation (i.e. cross dissolve between locations)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

I have four `UIView`s, positions on the four sides of my full view, e.g.

```
        View 3
View 4          View 2
      View 1
```

*(Note that the bottom view is offset a little bit)*

They are all 44x44 pixels and look exactly the same.

I have the views move counter clockwise to the next view's location (i.e. View 1 moves to View 2, View 2 moves to View 3, etc.), and View 4 moves to View 1, ***but not offset***. This part works normally, the code is as follows:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [view1 setFrame:view2.frame];
    [view2 setFrame:view3.frame];
    [view3 setFrame:view4.frame];
    [view4 setFrame:centerFrame];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self reloadData];
}];
```

`centerFrame` is view1's frame not offset.

In the method `reloadData`, the frames are move back to their original positions, and, because they all look the same, the only thing that users should see is the movement of the bottom view back to its offset position (although it is really changing from view4 to view1). This change looks a little bit sudden, and I wanted to animate it, **but I don't want the views to move back, just cross dissolve, so that only the bottom view looks like it changed**. I've tried:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    // Reset frames
} completion:nil];
```

and

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    // Reset frames
} completion:nil];
```

but both move the views. So my question,

### How do I animate a `UIView` frame change with a cross dissolve animation instead of moving between the points?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obvious suggestion, but have you tried playing around with the alpha?

Comment: @MendyK It would involve making another view with the same properties, changing the alphas of a few of the views, and moving the frames, and I was hoping there would be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can animated `alpha = 0`, update the frames in the completion block and then animated `alpha = 1`. Make the duration of each animation block 1/2 the usual so together they'll take the same time as the rotation event.

If you want to do a simultaneous dissolve then duplicate all the views, set their `alpha = 0`, update their frames and then animate the alpha of both groups:

`old views'.alpha = 0`
`new views'.alpha = 1`

a third solution - group all the views in a subview, copy the whole hierarchy and then animate the transition between them using `options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve`